# How to get count based on Values in SQL

Tags: sql

I've something to execute I need the count based on values. Here is my Table

```
"ORD_NUM","ORD_AMOUNT","ORD_DATE","CUST_CODE","AGENT_CODE","ORD_DESCRIPTION"
"200118"|"500"|"07/20/2008"|"C00023"|"A006"|"SOD"
"200120"|"500"|"07/20/2008"|"C00009"|"A002"|"SOD"
"200129"|"1000"|"07/20/2008"|"C00024"|"A006"|"SOD"
"200127"|"1000"|"08/20/2008"|"C00015"|"A003"|"SOD"
"200128"|"500"|"08/20/2008"|"C00009"|"A002"|"SOD"
"200128"|"500"|"09/20/2008"|"C00009"|"A002"|"SOD"
"200128"|"1000"|"09/20/2008"|"C00009"|"A002"|"SOD"
"200128"|"1000"|"10/20/2008"|"C00009"|"A002"|"SOD"
```

In the order amount we only have either 1000 or 500. We need to return the data count of 500 and 1000 for each date. EX:

```
Date      |1000Count|500Count
07/20/2008|    1    |   2
08/20/2008|    1    |   1
09/20/2008|    1    |   1
10/20/2008|    1    |   1
```

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting products; SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products, and use *very* different dialects of SQL. I've removed the tags, you'll need to (re)tag the product you are really using.

Comment: And please search for "pivot table" or "rows to columns" as this question has already been answered lots of times for both products here on SO.

Comment: @Shadow, I'm not sure how can we use Pivot Table in SQL?

Comment: @Chanikya this is why I suggested you to search SO. Pivoting is quite database specific. An SQl server solutionis unlikely to work in mysql, while mysql solution may work in ms sql server, but may not be efficient.

Comment: This is simple two times conditional count/sum with a GROUP BY date.

Comment: Please look solution https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/cdb322eb262119f272bab4f02b747250/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! to [SlavaRozhnev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3399356/slava-rozhnev)

```
select 
d,
count(case when amount = 500 then 1 end)    count500,
count(case when amount = 1000 then 1 end)   count1000
from test
group by d;
```

Gives Result :

```
+============+==========+===========+
| d          | count500 | count1000 |
+============+==========+===========+
| 2023-01-01 | 4        | 2         |
| 2023-01-02 | 1        | 1         |
| 2023-01-03 | 0        | 1         |
| 2023-01-04 | 1        | 0         |
+------------+----------+-----------+
```